# How to get OWIN Database Context in Database First Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dbcontext, owin

I've worked for days getting Identity Framework to work on my database first project.  The book that I have appears only to explain how to implement it using database first, but it mentioned OWIN.

I can see from the code first version that we can get an OWIN instance of a database context by calling a static `Create` method on the database context that returns an instance of itself.

Isn't OWIN compatible with database first models and database contexts?  If so, how do I get an instance of my database context using OWIN?

This is how you do it within code first:

**Database Context**

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser> {

    public AppIdentityDbContext() : base("IdentityDb") {}

    public static Create() {
        return new AppIdentityDbContext();
    }
}
```

Calling from OWIN start class:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(AppIdentityDbContext.Create);
```

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity.aspx

Comment: If you solve your problem using this link, please post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that the OWIN stuff isn't directly related to whether your application uses Entity Framework code first or database first.

The OWIN context is used to get to the UserManager, RoleManager etc. for ASP.NET Identity Framework.  The DbContext specified in this context is really for use solely by these classes and not just for general use within your ASP.NET MVC application.

I'm now using a IoC Container to inject my DbContext into my controllers within my projects.  (I'm using Ninject, but there are others such as Unity, MEF)